# JavaScript, Dynamic Regex, Replace everything between and including delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

**Text To Remove:**

---

I am trying to remove a line of text from a file.
Everything between `<%'/testStart'%>` and `<%'/testEnd'%`>` including the delimiters.

`<%'/testStart'%> Some text with other random characters in between <%'/testEnd'%>`

**JavaScript:**

---

I have tried this with no luck. Well, at one point I had it working with everything hard coded in the RegExp. But I have tried so many ways I can't remember what I did. Basically I think I am just not escaping something properly.

```
var p       = "/test"; //this is dynamic

var start   = "<%'" + p + "Start" + "'%>";
var end     = "<%'" + p + "End" + "'%>";

var regex   = new RegExp("\\" + start + "[^:]\\" + end);
var newData = data.replace(regex,"");
```

**Expected Result:**

---

Completely remove this line.

```
<%'/testStart'%> Some text with other random characters in between <%'/testEnd'%>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Match Inside with a Lazy `.*?`**

Replace your inner section `"[^:]\\"` with `".*?"`

```
var regex   = new RegExp( start + ".*?" + end );
```

The effect is to match everything up to the end parameter.

**Explanation**

The star quantifier in `.*?` is made "lazy" by the `?` so that the dot only matches as many characters as needed to allow the next token to match (shortest match). Without the `?`, the `.*` first matches the whole string, then backtracks only as far as needed to allow the next token to match (longest match).

Comment: You're very welcome, thanks for the green checkmark. :)